# How to add a class to an attribute group?

Tags: javascript, class, group

hi this is the js  code where magento generates new groups in admin:

```
 addGroup : function() {
                        var group_name = prompt("<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Please enter a new group name') ?>","");
                        group_name = group_name.strip();
                        if( group_name == '' ) {
                            this.addGroup();
                        } else if( group_name != false && group_name != null && group_name != '' ) {

                            if (!editSet.validateGroupName(group_name, 0)) {
                                return;
                            }

                            var newNode = new Ext.tree.TreeNode({
                                    text : group_name.escapeHTML(),
                                    cls : 'folder',
                                    allowDrop : true,
                                    allowDrag : true
                                });
                            TreePanels.root.appendChild(newNode);
                            newNode.addListener('beforemove', editSet.groupBeforeMove);
                            newNode.addListener('beforeinsert', editSet.groupBeforeInsert);
                            newNode.addListener('beforeappend', editSet.groupBeforeInsert);
                            newNode.addListener('click', editSet.register);
                        }
                    },
```

I want to add to the last group a class: 
I tried using this : `jQuery(".x-tree-node").last().addClass("test");` I put this code after this line  `newNode.addListener('click', editSet.register);`. It does not do anything. After that I tried smth like this: I change this line:

```
text : group_name.escapeHTML(),   into this :   `text : "<span class='testare'>"+group_name.escapeHTML()+</span>,`
```

It works, but it totally messed up the drag & drop. So how can i add a class to the last group added  ?

I tried also like this :

```
 var newNode = new Ext.tree.TreeNode({
                                    text : group_name.escapeHTML(),
                                    cls : 'folder',
                                    allowDrop : true,
                                    allowDrag : true,
                                    className : "testare"

                                });
```

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery(newNode).addClass()` instead of wrapping the 'text' in spans?

Comment: thx for the tip, but it does not do anything

Comment: Hm, have you tried vanilla javascript? I tried stuff in the js console for testing and it looks like jQuery is not defined.

Comment: I put this : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.boozzr.com/jq/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>    AT THE BEGINNING OF THE FILE

Comment: I didn't hear about vanilla js

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: vanilla javascript means pure javascript without lilbrary, but if you added jQeury yourself it should be defined. I think the problem might be that you add your jQuery line too early. `TreePanels.root.appendChild(newNode)` does sound like it is added to the dom, but that's not neccessarily so. Check for function which render the TreePanels and add your jQuery after that function.

Comment: I added this  jQuery("#"+id).siblings(".x-tree-node").addClass("test");    AT the end of the function addGroupFront, but with no result :((

Comment: Maybe it is impossible. hmm

Comment: How about you try to figure out the events this class fires and write a separate js file to hook into them? I haven't been heavily enough involved with this section to be able to offer more than ideas unfortunately.

Comment: Just looking at your site in inspector mode there is a jQuery error that is probably stopping any progress you have.